# How to forward client IP address from CloudFlare to Kubernetes NGINX ingress controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, cloudflare, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I'm using CloudFlare as DNS server for the system and need of whitelist IP for some domains of the system. I managed to do this but when I enable `Proxy status` feature for domain on CloudFlare I get `403 Forbidden` error because CloudFlare forwards its own IP for `ingress` instead of client IP address.
I found a tutorial [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786).
Is there any other way to solve this problem?
Here is the CloudFlare configuration.

[image]

Here is the `ingress` configuration.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: admin-ingress
  namespace: machine-learning
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 184.90.9.99,183.88.6.88
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "admin.xxx.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: admin-service
                port:
                  name: http
```

And this is the error I get

[image]

Any contribution is greatly appreciated.
Best regards,

Comment: Do you have access of your Nginx Config file ?

Comment: do you have access of you Nginx config file ?

Comment: @UmairLatif Yes, I can.

Answer (score 2):

Please add this line
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
in your Nginx config file to forward the original client IP address to the server.

Answer (score 1):

try this https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#configuration-snippet

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

Comment: I don't know what's the difference is. But adding it as server-snippet worked for me.
```nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;```